# Pure NetBeans doesn't work

Tags: java, ide, netbeans6.5

I had system: ubuntu-9.04-amd64. I installed IDE NetBeans 6.5 from official default repositories. Everything worked correctly.

---

But now, I decided to use ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.

I formated parts of my hard with: (`/` and `/usr`). `/home` remains as before. I've correctly installed ubuntu-9.10, correctly (probably) installed IDE NetBeans 6.5.

But NOW, I even can't create simplest java application using this IDE.
If I use CommandLine to compile java classes, everything works (`~/javac someclass.java | java`).

---

If I launch IDE (NB 6.5), then File->New Project-> This New Project is created, but isn't compiled: if put (F6) error is shown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: -g:
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:250)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:221)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.createJavacTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.createJavacTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.CompilationInfoImpl.getJavacTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.CompilationInfo.getElements(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.SourceUtils$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.SourceUtils$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runUserActionTaskImpl(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runUserActionTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.SourceUtils.isMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectUtil.isMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider.isSetMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider.getTargetNames(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.ui.ScanDialog.runWhenScanFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider.invokeAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.MainProjectAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.LookupSensitiveAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.windows.TopComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2897)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2814)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6040)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1848)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:704)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:969)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:841)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:668)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4502)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
[catch] at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

---

What can I do to compile simplest application using IDE. I must make my work, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks to be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/401589.

My understanding is that there are actually 2 solutions:

- Install NetBeans 6.7 **without** importing the settings from 6.5 (this would be my recommendation).
- Downgrade libnb-javaparser-java 6.7-0ubuntu1 to 6.5-0ubuntu1.